# Why when I put the braces the code will be infinite loop what is the reason?

Tags: java

when I put the braces for if Statement the code output is infinite loop and when I remove the braces it works correctly.

This is the code:

```
int gcd = 1;
int k = 2;
while (k <= number1 && k <= number2)
{
    System.out.println("this is k " + k);
    System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
    if(number1 % k == 0 && number2 % k == 0)
    {
        gcd = k;
        k++;
        System.out.println("this is k " + k);
        System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about *where* the variable `k` is updated.

Comment: To update your question with proper code use [edit] option. Also to properly format your code use code-snippet (`{}` icon from editors menu). Don't post your code as image because http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766

Comment: Try debugging, the problem is obvious, pay attention to your counter `k`

Comment: @Pshemo that question is a duplicate XD

Comment: @TheProgrammer You mean the meta question? Yes it is, but I still like to link to that particular answer rather than entire question. If someone would like to read more about this problem as you noted it is linked to bigger question :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the **k** value is **never** **updated** if you put it in the if statement. When you remove the braces, the code becomes this

```
if(number1 % k == 0 && number2 % k == 0)
    gcd = k;
k++;
System.out.println("this is k " + k);
System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
```

The only line that's in the if loop is the `gcd=k` line.

This means that the k value is always increasing every time you go through the while loop.

**If** you put it in the if statement, k might never go in because of the restraint on the if statement and therefore it never increase so it's always <= number1 and <= number2. And there, you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you where you added the braces causes `k` to only be incremented when the `if` statement evaluates to `true`. So, if the `if` statement isn't true, `k` isn't incremented, and the `while` loop continues forever because the `while` loop condition never changes.

```
int gcd = 1;
int k = 2;
while (k <= number1 && k <= number2)
{
    System.out.println("this is k " + k);
    System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
    if(number1 % k == 0 && number2 % k == 0)
    {
        gcd = k;
        k++; // THIS needs to be outside the if statement
        System.out.println("this is k " + k);
        System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
    }
}
```

instead you should have it like this:

```
int gcd = 1;
int k = 2;
while (k <= number1 && k <= number2)
{
    System.out.println("this is k " + k);
    System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
    if(number1 % k == 0 && number2 % k == 0)
    {
        gcd = k;
    }
    k++; 
    System.out.println("this is k " + k);
    System.out.println("this is gcd " + gcd);
}
```